# Starting Unitests on GUI Button Click

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to start unitests when user clicks a button on gui - for it i want to use simplepygui ,
i am wondering is it possible to do so if kindly suggest a way to implement

**Sample Unitest code**
class Sampletestclass(unittest.TestCase):

```
    def test_1_State(self):
       
        self.assertTrue(2 > 9)
        print('1')

    def test_2_State(self):
        print("2")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

[image: Sample Gui]

**GUI Code**

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Button('Start'),
     ]
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == 'Start':
        # how to handle starting unitest here 


    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED or event == 'Quit':

        break


window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

For Anyone Who would be trying similar Was Able to get it to work by calling

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

inside start event

Answer (score 0):

You can call `unittest.main(exit=False)` not to exit and add one `sg.Output` to capture output.

```py
import unittest
import PySimpleGUI as sg

class Sampletestclass(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_1_State(self):
        self.assertTrue(2 > 9)
        print('1')

    def test_2_State(self):
        print("2")

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
layout = [[sg.Button('Start Test')], [sg.Output(size=(80, 25), key='-OUTPUT-')]]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)

i = 0
while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Start Test':
        i += 1
        window['-OUTPUT-'].update(f'Test {i}\n\n')
        unittest.main(exit=False)
    # print(event, values)

window.close()
```

Comment: thanks a lot jason I was able to run also with your method however there is a thing with sg.output i am struggling . if i am adding html test runner in unittestmain() the sg.output isn't getting printed if I remove html test runner  then the output in sg.ouput is displayed any way I can fix it 

unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output="somepath")exit=False)